# controlling the order in which the partitions are processed in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

So, for an optimal usage of my cluster CPU, I would like to have my partitions processed roughly in the order given by `MyPartitioner.getPartition(key)`. I know they are processed in parallel and their processing order cannot be fully controlled but at least can I control the order in which the driver submits tasks to the executors ?

Something like :

```
 task 0 - process partition 0
 task 1 - process partition 1
 ...
 task n - process partition n
```

Comment: what is the goald behind this ? if you want to maximize  your cpu usage, your partitions size should be equal. why not using repartition or coalasce ?

Comment: I know that but I cannot do the repartition nor I cannot make the partitions equal.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, One cannot control the processing order of partitions in spark. The only thing that one can do is to make sure the partitions are more or less equal